# Improve transcription accuracy with speech adaptation boost when using google telephony?

Tags: dialogflow-es, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, dialogflow-cx

I know how we can provide the [audio config](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/QueryInput) to improve the ASR when using some third party telephony partners like twilio etc.
But how can we provide the audio config for boosting and improving ASR when using google telephony gateway?

Answer (score 1):

To improve speech recognition for Dialogflow phone gateway, if you are using [Dialogflow ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs) you can enable both settings under Speech tab > SPEECH RECOGNITION QUALITY.

[image]

Enabling [Enhanced speech models](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/data-logging) for [Dialogflow phone gateway](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/phone-gateway) integration only supports the following [languages](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/phone-gateway#lang):

- English (en) English
- US (en-US)

For more information, you may refer to the following links:

- [Auto Speech Adaptation Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/speech-adaptation)
- [Data logging and enhanced speech models](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/data-logging)

You may also want to look into using [webhook for iterative confirmation of spoken sequences](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/tutorials/sequences) to help with speech recognition.

Answer (score 0):

The audio config boosting and improving should be the same using Google telephony gateway. You can refer to this [article](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/detect-intent-audio#detect-intent-audio-python) for a sample implementation of the audio configuration on an agent.